# How to create a table (and nothing else) in Latex

Tags: tables

I like the look of the tables LaTeX makes (using `booktabs`). However, I cannot use LaTeX to format my entire document, as it must be written in Word. I would like to make a table with `LaTeX`, save it as a `.pdf` image file, which I can then paste into Word. Is there any easy way to make such a small document in `LaTeX`? Thanks

Comment: Use the `standalone` document class.

Comment: I wouldn't do this, if you have to use word, use word, getting the fonts and style to be coherent with the rest of the document is going to be hard otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `standalone` class and get `.jpg` on the fly

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,outext=.jpg}]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  Here & there & where \\\midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details, see section 4.6, page 15 of `standalone` manual.

Comment: Check the same folder for `.jpg` file.

Comment: I didn't actually get a .jpg file (maybe Ubuntu's fault?) but a .pdf works fine. Thanks

Comment: Do you have Imagemagick installed? That is the program used to get the jpg,png,etc. **If it's installed, you need to enable `-shell-escape` in the compiler.**  If so, the file would be in the same directory as the pdf would have gone, and have the same title. If not, install Imagemagick through package manager or sudo apt-get install imagemagick in a terminal. If you use TeXStudio you need merely to add to the preamble `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]`. Or else go through configuration preferences.

Comment: @GuidoJorg Thanks for the comment. I was in a hurry. :-)

Comment: It is a bad idea to convert text to jpeg. Converting to png is much better.

Comment: @Aditya I agree. But what more harm it can  do than using word itself? `;-)`. BTW, I think word won't accept `.png` as such. That is why I used `.jpg`.